# iPhone won't ask to trust computer again

Tags: windows-10, backup, iphone, photos, picture-import-wizard

I accidentally tapped "Don't trust" on my iPhone after connecting it to my Windows 10 PC and planning to import the latest pictures and videos I have taken during the summer. This is part of my backup routine and I do it every couple of months, but I believe this is the first time I clicked the wrong option.

The problem is when I disconnect and reconnect the phone, it doesn't ask me again whether to trust or not to trust my computer.

I quickly googled how to fix the problem and have so far tried the following options:

- Changed the autoplay selection on the PC
- Changed the PIN on the iPhone
- Rebooted the PC
- Rebooted the iPhone
- Ran Windows Update on the PC and rebooted again
- Resat location and privacy settings on the phone
- Resat network settings on the phone

The only suggestion I didn't yet try is to install iTunes. I'm not yet quite desperate enough to go that far. I think I'd actually rather buy a new computer rather than going through the hassle of installing and using iTunes. I still have several traumas from attempting to use iTunes for some simple task in the past.

I suppose I could just wait for a couple of weeks. At some point the phone will have to ask me again.

But there HAS to be a simpler and easier way for a user to force the phone to forget a mistaken entry like this. Does anybody have the answer?

By the way, I am looking for a solution which is as precise as possible, so resetting everything, reinstalling everything or replacing everything are not my preference. I'm thinking, Apple can't actually force me to start completely from scratch just because I hit the wrong button? Fingers crossed. Thanks.

Edit: Just to make it perfectly clear, I am not using iTunes on the PC and never have. My import routine is navigating to "This PC" -> "Devices and drivers" and right clicking on "Apple iPhone" which has appeared in File Explorer. The phone does appear in File Explorer as usual, but when I click on "Import pictures and videos", a dialog box appears saying "No pictures or videos were found on this device". This, I imagine, stems from the lack of trust on the phone's part. Apparently, this seems outside the box to some, though I just see it as letting Windows handle stuff, iTunes otherwise handles. It has worked fine since 2013 on three different iPhones and three different PCs.

Update 1: The phone still doesn't ask me today, the day after the problem occurred. I have tested plugging the phone into a coworker's PC (identical to mine) and the question popped up immediately on the phone. Meanwhile, since the problem occurred, my phone has forgotten all wifi's and which apps may access camera, photos etc, but it won't forget NOT to trust my PC.

Update 2: Two days later I was asked after ending the YourPhone.exe process on the PC (see posted answer for details).

Comment: If you "don't trust" then it should ask you every time. Trust is remembered, don't trust isn't. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202778 Anyway, the trust settings are in the phone, not in the computer. Best guess if it doesn't spring the warning is you disabled the helper.

Comment: You could install libimobile tools and manually execute `idevicepair pair` to start the pairing process.

Comment: I use and maintain iTunes. It works well with the Trust relationship.

Comment: @Tetsujin: What Apple Support says about trust in that post is not helpful. Resetting privacy and location may cause the phone to ask whether to trust previously trusted computers, but it does NOT ask whether to trust previously untrusted computers. At least in this particular case.

Comment: It gives you 7 things to try. Until you've tried them all I don't really think you can call it unhelpful. Resetting Loc/Privacy resets the entire list. It should ask on ALL computers after that. It also says to check the helper is running. Presumably without that, there's no trigger being sent for the prompt. I know what Windows users are like for switching off things they think are 'unnecessary' ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin: I have not had iTunes on this computer at any point, so iTunes Mobile Device Helper is obviously not running, and it never has. The phone usually was able to ask for trust in spite of that fact. This has now changed because I tapped the wrong answer. As you pointed out earlier, the trust settings are on the phone, and a couple of hours ago the phone asked me whether to trust or not, so the trigger was there all right. But as soon as I tapped "Dont trust", the phone seemed to decide never to trust that computer again. So this is not caused by uninstalling or disabling the helper.

Comment: You need to add all this new information to your question. How is anyone supposed to be able to guess you're trying to do this without any Apple support structure installed?

Comment: @Tetsujin: The phone also shows up in File Explorer when I connect it, so Windows knows it's there. The computer just isn't allowed to view anything or import anything, because the phone seemingly won't trust it ever again.

Comment: You're trying to work outside the box. I've no clue how it's meant to work without the Apple support.

Comment: I thought my question made it perfectly clear that I'm not using iTunes.

Comment: Sorry - if you read it carefully it does… but most people [including me, obviously] would assume that anyone subscribing to the Apple way of doing things wouldn't duck installing the software that enables those things to be done. You basically have a non-standard method, which might be tougher to diagnose.

Comment: @Tetsujin: If you view it as a non-standard way, I can see that I could be clearer in my question. But I honestly thought this was a pretty standard way to do it. I asked around in my circle of friends and coworkers and most of them use either my way (cable to PC and Windows import without iTunes) or iCloud or Google Photos. Only a couple use iTunes. Having an iPhone doesn't necessarily mean that everyone wants to use iTunes on their PC. I see iTunes and Windows as kind of a clash, and I have been quite happy with letting Windows handle the import from iPhone. Until yesterday.

Comment: Sure - I understand. Most of my compatriots use Macs rather than Windows, where all this stuff is simply built-in, including photo import, which I know on Windows means you have to mount the phone as an actual storage device. On Mac you never need to do that, there's a dedicated import structure. Wish you luck, but it's a bit outside my experience.

Answer (score -1):

I have now succeeded in making the phone ask again. Turns out, the problem was on the computer.

I have this proprietary software installed called CopyTrans which allowed me to transfer some older pictures into my iPhone when I bought the phone a year ago. Haven't used it since. In order to troubleshoot, I opened CopyTrans Control Center, then updated and opened the CopyTrans Photo app. Then I reconnected my iPhone and it asked me whether I wanted to trust the computer. So CopyTrans was able to initiate the prompt on the phone.

I then went to This PC, right clicked the Apple iPhone and quickly imported my pictures and videos successfully.

Afterwards, I closed CopyTrans and made sure its processes were not running in the background. This caused the phone to revert to the state where it does not ask whether to trust the computer and the computer is unable to access pictures on the phone.

But at this point I noticed a background process called YourPhone.exe which was in suspended mode. According to several seemingly trustworthy sources, this is a built in Windows program which allows Windows to work with a connected phone. I ended the process and expected it to be necessary to restart it somehow, but as it appears, importing pictures works fine after ending the YourPhone.exe process. I suppose Windows may have some additional processes to handle the phone connection. At least it works, even if YourPhone.exe isn't running.

The process seemed to be suspended to improve system performance (had a green leaf in the task manager).

According to the details in Task Manager, the .exe file was changed on August 6th, so there might possibly have been a recent update which can cause the problem.

At least I can confirm that after a while, YourPhone.exe is back running, and is again suspended in order to improve system performance. And when I connect the iPhone, Windows is unable to access my iPhone's pictures and videos and cannot import anything.

So ending the YourPhone.exe process solves the problem.